# Finding set theory book with terminologies about set-theoretical ideals and filters

Tags: set-theory, ideals, book-recommendation, filters

I am using Jech's book for studying set theory. While surfing MSE I've encountered some terminologies I didn't know such as

- $\phi \text{ mod } I$
- Normal ideal
- $I$-positive $I$-null (associating ideal with measure)

By googling the terms I now know their meaning but I'm not used to using them. Are there some books that use these terminologies about ideals(and filters)?

Thank you.